# How to change the keypad programatically to specified language

Tags: ios, ios7

I have used the following code to convert my app to other language so that I can achieve localisation programmatically but my key pad does not change to the specified language

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"zh", nil]
forKey:@"AppleLanguages"]; 

[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
```

How can I change my keypad for specific language?

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately you cannot change the language of the keyboard. This is a user setting, it is not available via any APIs.